# Setting webkitspeechRecognition to state and changing language

Tags: reactjs, webkitspeechrecognition

So, I have set

```
let recognition = new SpeechRecognition;
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';

this.setState({
    recognition
});
```

`console.log(this.state.recognition)` gives me the speechrecognition object.
because I shouldn't direct mutate the state with `this.state.recognition.lang = 'ja-JP'`, I try to create a new object to set the recognition state to:

```
let newObject = {...this.state.recognition, lang: 'ja-JP'}
```

However, `console.log(newObject)` returns `{ lang: 'ja-JP' }` and the rest of the properties are not cloned.

Is this a problem with the webkitspeechrecognition api and is there a workaround to getting it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object spread operator (`...`) returns the enumerable properties of an `Object` as key-value pairs. But not all types that inherit from the `Object` prototype have enumerable properties, and it looks like the native `SpeechRecognition` type is one of those--there are no iterable keys, just non-enumerable attributes. (So, `...(new SpeechRecognition)` doesn't even throw an error; it has dutifully returned the zero enumerable properties of `recognition`. This is actually not all that surprising, there are lots of built-in Javascript object types that do not have enumerable properties.)

I think you will need to create a `new SpeechRecognition` instance with the desired `recognition.lang = 'ja-JP'`, and then `setState` to that. There is no spread or `.assign()` method that creates new `SpeechRecognition` instances from old ones, that I am aware of. I can see how this could create a situation in which there are multiple `SpeechRecognition` instances that the browser is allocating memory to; you might have to get creative and `delete` the reference to the old `SpeechRecognition` instance after `setState` is complete, so that garbage collection can do its work and leave you with just the one instance.